# How to create a performant table with echarts in each row

Tags: javascript, graphics, echarts

I have been using echarts for some time now and it has worked beautifully in various scenarios. However, I wanted to make a table where each row had multiple charts. The charts are quite simple (stripped down bar chart), but the performance is horrendous.

I'm using the SVG renderer

[image]

It takes 4.7 seconds to update 52 charts (I just call setOption with the new options).

[image: performance tab showing each echart setOption call]

It spends 85ms (avg) on each chart to Recalculate styles.

Is this something that echarts is not intended for? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Echarts is 1mb of code, it's overkill for essentially sparkline charts. Try this instead, I've had over 1000 charts updating in well under a second. 
https://github.com/railsjazz/peity_vanilla

Comment: I use echarts for other parts of my app witth more complex charts. I would prefer to not increase the dependencies of the project

Comment: even so, initializing a 1MB codebase 52 times (separately) will not be performant. It's 4k and reuses its resources unlike echarts https://github.com/railsjazz/peity_vanilla/blob/main/dist/peity-vanilla.min.js 
Alternatively you could try performing your setOptions update asynchronously.

Comment: What type did you use for the table? A heatmap?

Comment: I used A simple bar chart